# Unnecessary (and incorrect) email

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I received an email from Stack Exchange informing me of a recruiter's interest in my resume on Stack Overflow Careers.  So far so good.

I responded at the Stack Overflow Careers site to the recruiter saying "Thanks, but no thanks".

The recruiter then follows up with a thanks to *my* response.

Stack Exchange sees that and sends me an email saying that the recruiter wants to contact me!

I realize that the bot is simply detecting a new message on the Careers site and notifying me.  However using that heuristic alone is a tad simplistic.  That can probably be applied only once per thread -- the first time.

Answer (score 11):

We send an email any time you get a direct message through Careers.  All it should say is "You received a message from X" and then the content of the message.  This is consistent with most other sites that I can think of, and it seems like a bad idea to *not* notify people immediately when they get a message.  Naturally we rate limit the messages an employer can send so they don't spam you, but this seems like a legitimate follow-up email.

If you got a second message that seemed to indicate that this was a recruiter contacting you about a new job opportunity, then that sounds like a bug (or the recruiter somehow started a new message thread).

Comment: Well if you *really* cared, you could build a huge AI to determine whether a message is important to the user or not.  *reproachful stare*

Comment: The subject of the email indeed just says "1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox".  However the _body_ includes the line which is in the format "<MESSAGE_TITLE> wants to contact you on Stack Overflow Careers" where <MESSAGE_TITLE> is the title (subject) of the message on the Careers site.  I am just picking nits with the "wants to contact you" part of it.  In my case the recruiter was not trying to contact me. S/he was just thanking me.  Anyway I concur with @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm 's desire for more than less. 'Tis just that when the bar is set high the expectations rise as well ;-)

Comment: @Sri ah, fair enough - if your quarrel is with how the message is *worded*, that's a different matter. (I thought you were asking for the notification to be removed completely.)

Answer (score 8):

What if the recruiter sends you an *important* message in the same thread (like a change to some circumstance because of which you declined), and you miss it because the bot notifies you only once per thread?

I'd rather have one message too many than one too few. After all, this isn't LinkedIn with its frequent dribble of meaningless updates.

Comment: Agreed.  As noted above I am just picking nits maybe 'cos the various SO sites have spoiled me by setting the bar so high :-)